# JavaFX canvas: Make image "flat"

Tags: javafx

Is there any option to rotate an image at the (3D) y-Axis by using the GraphicsContext in a JavaFX canvas?

I thought about applying an affine transformation. Sadly I only got that far that I was able to shear and rotate the image which does not result in the perspective I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/effect/PerspectiveTransform.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to 'fabian'!

The Solution is a *PerspectiveTransform* ([Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/effect/PerspectiveTransform.html)).

This code for example returns a Transform for the desired effect.

```
    static PerspectiveTransform getTransform(double x, double y, double width) {

    double hf = 0.3; // Height Factor (0 < hf < 1)
    double df = 0.2; // Deepth-Factor (0 < df < 0.5)

    double heightDif = (1 - hf) * width;

    PerspectiveTransform pt = new PerspectiveTransform();

    pt.setUlx(x + (df * width));  // upper left x
    pt.setUly(y + heightDif);  // upper left y

    pt.setUrx(x + width - (df * width));  // upper right x
    pt.setUry(y + heightDif);  // upper right y

    pt.setLlx(x);  // lower left x
    pt.setLly(y + width * hf + heightDif);  // lower left y

    pt.setLrx(x + width);  // lower right x
    pt.setLry(y + width * hf + heightDif); lower right y
    return pt;
}
```

The Transform can be applyied by performing `canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setEffect(getTransform(...));`

Any square image, drawn at x and y will be bend like it is shown in the picture.